# How to sink field value to nested JSON with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

For input:

```js
var json = 
[  
   {  
      "inventory":{  
         "name":"SF Home",
         "items":{  
            "items":[  
               {  
                  "id":"d98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a",
                  "name":"SICP (functional programming)"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9",
                  "name":"Learn Python the hard way!"
               },
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "inventory":{  
         "name":"SEA Home",
         "items":{  
            "items":[  
               {  
                  "id":"7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28",
                  "name":"FP in Scala"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
]
```

This is the expected output:

```js
var expected = [ 
  { 
    id: 'd98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a',
    name: 'SICP (functional programming)',
    inventory_name: "SF Home" 
  },
  { 
    id: 'fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9',
    name: 'Learn Python the hard way!',
    inventory_name: "SF Home" 
  },
  { 
    id: '7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28',
    name: 'FP in Scala',
    inventory_name: "SEA Home"
  }
]
```

However, I can only achieve below result (without `inventory_name`) by using lodash (See [Repl.it playground](https://repl.it/@Yik_SanSan/retrieve-nested-value-from-complex-json)):

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const actual = _.chain(json).map("inventory.items.items").flatten().value();
```

Actual output:

```
[ { id: 'd98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a',
    name: 'SICP (functional programming)' },
  { id: 'fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9',
    name: 'Learn Python the hard way!' },
  { id: '7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28',
    name: 'FP in Scala' } ]
```

`inventory_name` is missing from the result. However I want to sink `inventory_name` down to nested JSON. Can anyone help fill the gap using lodash? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to require an external library like Lodash for this - you can use `flatMap` to extract each `name` and `items` array, and create a new array composed of the items objects with their associated `inventory_name`s:

```js
var json=[{"inventory":{"name":"SF Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"d98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a","name":"SICP (functional programming)"},{"id":"fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9","name":"Learn Python the hard way!"},]}}},{"inventory":{"name":"SEA Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28","name":"FP in Scala"}]}}}]

const output = json.flatMap(({ inventory: { name, items }}) => (
  items.items.map(item => ({ ...item, inventory_name: name }))
));
console.log(output);
```

Or, without `flatMap`, you can `reduce`:

```js
var json=[{"inventory":{"name":"SF Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"d98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a","name":"SICP (functional programming)"},{"id":"fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9","name":"Learn Python the hard way!"},]}}},{"inventory":{"name":"SEA Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28","name":"FP in Scala"}]}}}]

const output = json.reduce((a, { inventory: { name, items }}) => a.concat(
  items.items.map(item => ({ ...item, inventory_name: name }))
), []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this without lodash via the [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method as detailed below:

```js
var json=[{"inventory":{"name":"SF Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"d98e55d3-8ada-4937-bded-d6f8d948eb4a","name":"SICP (functional programming)"},{"id":"fc490ac2-449e-4aaf-95c5-a993ec220ec9","name":"Learn Python the hard way!"}]}}},{"inventory":{"name":"SEA Home","items":{"items":[{"id":"7126a7c2-3328-4bb4-b425-66adb8ad9b28","name":"FP in Scala"}]}}}];

/* Iterate over input json and reduce the nested arrays into a single flat
   array for expected */
var expected = json.reduce((result, item) => {

  /* For inventory item of this iteration, map each item of
  item.inventory.items.items to the data shape for items in the resulting
  expected array. The mapped result is concatenated to the result which 
  will be returned to expected */
  return result.concat(item.inventory.items.items.map(inventory => {

    /* Map the id and name of current inventory, as well as
       item.inventory.name to inventory_name
    for each item of expected array */
    return {
      id: inventory.id,
      name: inventory.name,
      inventory_name: item.inventory.name
    }
  }))

}, []);

console.log(expected);
```